# Получение изображения или svg из полигонов, построенных на Яндекс.Карте

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

Строю на Яндекс.Карте несколько полигонов. Они имеют разную форму и цвет. Есть ли возможность каким-либо образом сохранить внешний вид этих полигонов в формате изображения или svg? Именно начертания, цвета и взаимное расположение полигонов, без карты.

Comment: Есть возможность сохранить данные и как изображение через canvas и как SVG-файл. А как вы стоите полигоны, какими инструментами? В виде чего они существуют на странице? И что имеется в виду под сохранить? Позволить пользователю скачать и сохранить файл? Загрузить на сервер?

Comment: Полигоны строятся из json файла и просто отображаются на карте. Файл обновляется раз в несколько дней - меняется цвет полигонов. В момент этого обновления я хочу также формировать и сохранять новое актуальное изображение или svg полигонов, чтобы использовать его на другой странице сайта

Comment: Ничего не понял, ну тогда и сохраняйте эти json-файлы и получайте информацию для других страниц из него же. Зачем сохранять в виде SVG или изображения, если можно дешево закодировать данные полигонов.

Comment: В json-файле имеются географические координаты, с помощью которых полигоны строятся на карте. На другой же странице карты не будет, соответственно из json по координатам построить их там я не смогу. Поэтому мне и нужно в каком-то виде сохранить именно внешний вид полигонов

Comment: Вона чего... Надо как-то получить путь этого многоугольника относительно окна просмотра или карты скорее. Каким методом строите эти полигоны? `ymaps.Polygon` ? Метод `IPolygonGeometry.getPixelGeometry([options])` что возвращает? Надо получить координаты точек не географические, а пиксельные, относительно верхней и левой границы карты.

Comment: Я создаю менеджер объектов и после получения данных из json файла просто отдаю ему описание объектов:  objectManager.add(geoJson). Соответственно ymaps.Polygon не используются и getPixelGeometry как я понимаю применить не к чему